# Finding Stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have the following differential equation

*dX$_t$ = (r$\mu$X$_t$ + $\frac{r(r-1)}{2}σ^2X_t$)dt + rσX$_t$dB$_t$*,

*X$_0$ = x*, with *x > 0*.

Here, *r>0*. I am having trouble figuring out how to find the process *X$_t$*. I would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ dX_t=\left(r\mu+\frac{1}{2}r(r-1)\sigma^2\right)X_tdt+r\sigma X_t dB_t $$
By application of Ito lemma, we have
$$d(\ln X_t)=\frac{1}{X_t}dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{X_t^2}\right)d[X_t,X_t]$$
therefore
$$d(\ln X_t)=\left(r\mu+\frac{1}{2}r(r-1)\sigma^2\right)dt+r\sigma  dB_t-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sigma^2dt$$
in other words
$$d(\ln X_t)=\left(r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right)dt+r\sigma  dB_t$$
thus
$$\ln X_t-\ln x_0=\left(r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right)t+r\sigma  B_t$$
finally we have
$$X_t=x_0\exp\left(\left[r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right]t+r\sigma  B_t\right)$$